# What is a object type of request in django?

Tags: django, request

If I write a view as 
`def view(request):`

What is type of the request (Django Object)? What are it's expected contents (is it a HTTP stream???)? What does the request look like esp after it has been dispatched by URLDispacther

Comment: Tutorials/documentation say/show what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time be more specific about what you need, iandotkelly is right.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/

From the docs:

> When a page is requested, Django creates an HttpRequest object that
>   contains metadata about the request. Then Django loads the appropriate
>   view, passing the HttpRequest as the first argument to the view
>   function. Each view is responsible for returning an HttpResponse
>   object.

Answer (score 2):

It's an [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) object.